# Disable background dim on ProgressDialog/AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I use an AsyncTask with a ProgressDialog in it.
This automatically causes a background dim of about 40%. I want to turn this dim off (0% dim), but what I tried, didn't work:

```
myLoadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
myLoadingDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
myLoadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
myLoadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = myLoadingDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.0f; 
myLoadingDialog.show();
```

The problem with that dim was, that I had to terminate my Tablet's SystemUI-Process to achieve a Kiosk mode (with no System-Bar) and the ProgressDialog dims everything but the area where the System-Bar was, so I have a bright border at the bottom of the screen.

If there is a way to get a complete fullscreen-dim, I would be also happy.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 100, accepted):

use

```
myLoadingDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHI‌​ND);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add this theme to solve this problem also

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the relative amount of dimming with the following:

```
window?.setDimAmount(0.2f)
```

This is set in onCreate of your dialog class.